# why we forget dreams when we wake up?

Tags: memory, sleep, dreams

What is the explanation for which we forget easily our dreams when we wake up?. It has a biological sense, such as to avoid to confuse reality world experiences with dream world experiences? or there are other psychological or psychoanalytic explanations?

I appreciate your help.